# How to select arrays in multidimensional array with a value in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

To put it right lets say I have an array `stores`-

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "store3"
  1 => "store"
  2 => "store2"
]
```

This is the array which holds values.

Other array `products` holds all the data:-

```
array:2 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "store" => "store"
    "product" => "1"
  ]
  1 => array:2 [▼
    "store" => "store"
    "product" => "4"
  ]
  2 => array:2 [▼
    "store" => "store2"
    "product" => "2"
  ]
  3 => array:2 [▼
    "store" => "store2"
    "product" => "3"
  ]
  4 => array:2 [▼
    "store" => "store3"
    "product" => "7"
  ]
  5 => array:2 [▼
    "store" => "store3"
    "product" => "11"
  ]
]
```

What I want is that a value is picked from `stores` array eg `store3` then it is compared with `products` array and being searched and extract all the arrays inside `products` array which has the `store` value `store3` and store it in another new array named `store3`

I have tried to do it but it was very wrong I mean it didn't work! I will post it if anyone say so but can anyone accomplish this?

My work:-

```
$temp = array();
  for($i=0; $i<count($stores); $i++)
  {
    //$stores[$i] = array();

    foreach($products as $p)
    {
      if(session($stores[$i]) == $p['store'])
      {
        if(count(session($stores[$i])) == 0)
        {
          $temp['product'] = $p['product'];
          session($stores[$i])->push($temp['product']);
        }
        else if(!in_array($p['product'],$stores[$i]))
        {
          $temp['product'] = $p['product'];
          session($stores[$i])->push($temp['product']);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: `array_filter` seems to be fitted for your needs, but you can also do it with a `foreach` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like below:-

```
$final_array = array();
foreach($array1 as $arr){
  foreach($array2 as $arr2){
     if($arr == $arr2['store']){
       $final_array[$arr]['product'][] = $arr2['product'];
     }
  }
}
echo "<pre/>";print_r($final_array);
```

Output:-https://eval.in/752498

Comment: This get the right idea! But the thing is I want to have separate arrays dynamically created for each store.

Comment: I actually did it :P right after putting the comment

Comment: @Alen  good that you did it yourself. glad to help you . cheers :):):)

Comment: sorry I thought I could mark another question as right!

Comment: Was just checking

Comment: @Alen  ok. But try not to do that again :):)

Comment: Yess sorry! Not so much familiar with StackOverFlow :)

Answer (score 1):

using [array_walk](http://php.net/array_walk)

```
$array = [];
array_walk($products, function ($value, $key) use ($stores, &$array) {
    $array[$value['store']][] = $value['product'];
});
```

live sample : https://3v4l.org/BfeMm

Answer (score 1):

using array filter

```
$store = 'store1';

$products = array_filter($products, function($product) use($store) {
    return (isset($product['store']) and $product['store'] == $store);
});

var_dump($products);
```

https://eval.in/752508

Answer (score 1):

I made a simple function to find products in store

```
function searchProduct($products,$storeName){
    $results =array();
    foreach($products as $product){
        if(in_array($storeName,array_values($product)))
           $results[] = $product;    
    }
    return $results;
 }
 print_r(searchProduct($products,'store3'));
```